# proving no limit exists at $ x_0 = 0 $ at $ \sin(1/x) $

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I should prove that there is no limit at $ x_0 = 0 $ in the function $$ f(x) = \sin({\frac{1}{x}}) $$with the sequences $ x_n = 1/(n\pi) $ and $ x_n= 1/(2n\pi + \pi/2) $

What would be the approach to do this?

My 2 sequences converging to zero as $ n \rightarrow \infty$
Is there any theorem?

Comment: You use the theorem that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $x$ iff for every sequence $x_n \to x_0$ we have that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Comment: is having a limit at $ x_0 $ (coming from both sides => the same) aquivalent to is continuous at $ x_0$ ?

Comment: no. The function must also be defined at $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) $

Comment: Im stuck by setting n = 0 then every function or sequence is undefined.. so how do I do it?

Comment: @DominiqueLüber You use the theorem I stated by plugging in the two sequences. Now, obviously, if $f$ is continuous, then any sequence $x_n$ which tends to $0$ must have that $f(x_n)$ tend to the same limit, iregardless of the sequence you choose to get there. Now, while $f(0)$ can't be defined by explicityly plugging in $x=0$, this result shows that there is no way we can define $f(0)$ such that the extension of $f$ to all non-negative real numbers is continuous at $0$ (contrast with, say, $x \sin (1/x)$).

Comment: hm. I'm confused about the sequence. why would anybody come up with this sequence and how does it affect my function. thats whats confusing me. is the sequence an approximation of the function? i dont know..

i will think about it but right now its not really clear to me

Comment: does anybody knows a youtube video about this kind of example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanna show that you have two subsequencies converging to 0 while the function series are not consistent. That is
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}\rightarrow 0$$
$$y_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2}\rightarrow 0$$
while
$$\sin\frac{1}{x_n}=\sin(n\pi)\rightarrow 0$$ 
$$\sin\frac{1}{y_n}=\sin(2n\pi+\pi/2)\rightarrow 1$$

Comment: so you just put in the sequence into the x variable? and then compared both limits or both function values?

Comment: Yes. If the limit of a series exists, then all subsequences towards that point have the same limit, that limit is precisely the limit of the series.

Comment: so both sequences converging? for n->inf but not for n->0? right? I need it more detailed.. to less information for me right now.. not clear enough. sorry

Comment: Yes. The n that makes $x_n$ converges to 0

Comment: yeah. for the sequence i got that. but the limit for n-> inf for the sin(.. is not defined? or its infinity?

Comment: You have assumed that $n$ is positive integer, so the limit does exist.

Comment: so how would you calculate that? i can see it from the graph, makes sense to me but how would you calculate it.. thats my problem. maybe there isn't any calcuation. just look and see that with every n the periodic function just repeats itself?

Comment: Exactly. You know $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $\sin(2n\pi+\pi/2)=1$ right? So the limit of a constant is precisely that constant.

Comment: ok now with the help of my book i think i got it know. if i want to calculate my limit at $ x_0 $ I need to find a sequence which has $x_0$ as limit/converges to $x_0$ so my limit c at the function exists if my function $ lim n-> inf f(x_n) = c $ mathematically maybe not 100% right, but my "point" to prove is x_0 and that should be my convergence for ALL sequences and then my limit is if i plug in the sequence into my function as a value  ( f(x_n) )

Comment: So to say it again. I need to find a sequence where x_n -> c but f(x_n) doesnt -> c